# Color by a bar graph by a fourth variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

So, I am trying to create a bar graph with ggplot2 that will color the fill of the graph by a fourth variable.

```
 df = data.frame(c(1,1,2,2,3), c("A","B","C","D","E"),  c(1:5 / 4), c("Y", "N", "Y", "N", "N"))
 names(df)[1:4] <- paste("var", 1:4, sep = "")
 df$var1 <- as.factor(df$var1)
 df$var2 <- as.factor(df$var2)
 df$var4 <- as.factor(df$var4)
 ggplot(df, aes(x = var1, y = var3, fill = var2)) + facet_wrap(~var1, scale = "free") + 
    geom_bar(position = "dodge", colour = "black", stat = "identity") + 
    scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1") + scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

What I am trying to do is set the color that shows up in the bar graphs to correspond with `var4`, but still facet the graphs by `var2`.  I have tried to put  `aes(fill = var4)` into the `geom_bar` part but that didn't give me the result I wanted.

I am also having a problem with the bars being stacked on each other that seems to change based on `var3` being a character or numeric.  To put this in context, `var1` would be a question ID, `var2` would be an answer ID, `var3` would be a percentage, and `var4` would be whether the answer is correct or not.

Comment: Do you want something like this? `ggplot(df, aes(x = var2, y = var3, fill=var4)) + facet_wrap(~var1, scale = "free") + 
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", colour = "black", stat = "identity") + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1") + scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) `?

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for.  Thank you, I didn't know that I should change it in the facet_wrap portion.

Comment: I have posted as answer too.

Comment: Thank you, sorry I'm still new to posting on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = var2, y = var3, fill=var4)) + facet_wrap(~var1, scale = "free") + 
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", colour = "black", stat = "identity") + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1") + scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

[image]